# Is it possible to detect the moment when a remote notification has been added to the notification center?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, unusernotificationcenter

There are two methods in `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` protocol related to the notification delivery. But both don't seem to satisfy my needs.

```
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
  willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
    withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
```

is called BEFORE the notification has been delivered. If you ask the notification center to give you all the delivered notifications the new one will be missing.

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
     withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(void))completionHandler
```

is called only if the user provides some response to the notification. There is also good old `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` but it is deprecated.

So is it even possible to be notified right after the Notification Center DID add a notification?

Comment: What's your use case here? I mean what are you trying to do?

Comment: delete the notification from the notification center. but it is not there

Comment: This kind of sounds like a problem that needs to be solved at the sender, not on the device: either have the sender send a silent notification instead, or get a message to the sender that it shouldn't send the thing in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a [Notification Content Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/customizing_the_appearance_of_notifications), this extension will be called when push notifications are received, with the goal of allowing the extension to enhance the notification before presenting it to the user ([wwdc session on advanced notifications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/708/)).

This way you have a chance to execute some code when notification arrive. You don't have to actually modify the notification.

Note that the code will execute in the context of the app extension, so you might need some more work if you want to execute something within the app.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is this:

> delete the notification from the notification center. but it is not
>   there

If you're trying to suppress or prevent the push notification from presenting. Then this is not possible, as of iOS 11.0 As to why, Apple didn't mention.

However, if you want to just remove a push, `UNUserNotificationCenter` has the following methods available for you to use:

```
// Notification requests that are waiting for their trigger to fire
open func getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: @escaping ([UNNotificationRequest]) -> Void)

open func removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers identifiers: [String])

open func removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()


// Notifications that have been delivered and remain in Notification Center. Notifications triggered by location cannot be retrieved, but can be removed.
open func getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler: @escaping ([UNNotification]) -> Void)

open func removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers identifiers: [String])

open func removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
```

Comment: but the notification hasn't been delivered yet. how is it supposed to get removed?

Comment: I really want to thank you for your response. However it doesn't help. The earliest moment I'm notified about the notification delivery is userNotificationCenter: willPresentNotification: method. However if I call getAllDeliveredNotifications the new one is not there. Do you see the problem? There's no way to delete the notification at this point because it is ABOUT to be delivered, but hasn't been delivered yet

Comment: it's weird. the notification gets deleted by removeAllDeliveredNotifications despite the fact it is not returned by getDeliveredNotifications. Seems like these two methods operate over two different sets of notifications

Comment: I see. I can check this on my project later today if you haven't found an answer. But correct me if I am wrong, what I am thinking you want to do is that when a push notification gets to the iOS Device (notification list) of the user, and your app is active, you'd like to remove such specific push notification from that list/screen of iOS. Correct?

Comment: I guess you have an answer, by Cristik. That's the most flexible way you could get.